# Playframework Scala Action Async multiple validations?

Tags: scala, playframework

In my Playframework application I use an Async Action to validate post data from frontend.

is there a way to do validation on two models?

at the moment it looks like this

```
request.body.asJson.map(_.validate[ContentModel] match { case JsSuccess(contentComponent, _) =>
```

But I send two different Models to backend.

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally a bad idea to conflate multiple possible data inputs to the same REST end point, and it kind of voids the whole point of REST.

If at all possible, I would create a separate route for the different data model, and have the client call a different end point depending on whatever condition is causing it to produce the different data payload.

```
POST /api/v1/process/a  controllers.Bla.doStuffA()
POST /api/v1/process/b  controllers.Bla.doStuffB()
```

In the backend, you can then have an ADT of the data model, if necessary, and have your route logic specialised to the leaves of that ADT, which behind the scenes use the same service methods for anything part of that ADT.

```
trait ContentModel
case class ContentModelA(....) extends ContentModel
case class ContentModelB(...) extends ContentModel
```

And now you could maybe:

```
def processModel(data: ContentModel) = {
  data match {
    case ContentModelA(...) =>
    case ContentModelB(...) =>
  }
}
```

So your `doStuffA` and `doStuffB` controller methods would look something like:

```
def doStuffA = Action.async { implicit req => req.body.asJson.map(_.validate[ContentModelA].map(processData) }

def doStuffB = Action.async { implicit req => req.body.asJson.map(_.validate[ContentModelB].map(processData) }
```

**If you must**

To answer your question in the strictest sense:

```
val jsonOpt = request.body.asJson

jsonOpt map { payload =>
  payload.validate[ContentModelA] match {
    case JsSuccess() => ... we have an A Model
    case JsError(err, paths) => 
      // couldn't deal with A, let's try B
      payload.validate[ContentModelB] match {
        case JsSuccess() => //we have a B
        case JsError(err, paths) => // oops, neither A nor B.
      }

  }
}
```

You could do this with a really fancy Shapeless coproduct, with Format proofs for all the types in the coproduct, and go from there, but I think that's blowing it out of the park.